# Symfony2 structure setup

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, localhost

Im almost new to Symfony2, I understand the Bundle, entity etc.

But my problem is with the structure.

I created a local virtualservers for development and i can't start until i dont know what im doing and how will it work.

So my current DocumentRoot is: http://mysite.localhost/ -> /var/www/mysite

I installed Symfony like this

/var/www/mysite
 - app 
 - bin
 - src
 - vendor
 - web

May I need to generate a bundle for "index page" or i need the use the app.php/ ?

I mean i would my page starts with http://mysite.localhost/

What i need to do?
Where i need to generate Bundles?
Im confused.

Thank you so much

Best Regards,
Krisztian

---

For first, thanks the replies!

Now I modified like you adviced guys. Now when i write to browser http://mysite.localhost/ it will be http://mysite.localhost/app.php/ with 404 error. It doesn't matter that my DirectoryIndex is app.php or app_dev.php it is always pointing to app.php.

Is it normal? If it is, then how can I link a Bundle for main page or something like that?

Here is my sites-available/mysite file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mysite.localhost
ServerAlias mysite
ServerAdmin info@something.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/web/
DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddCharset ISO-8859-2  .iso8859-2  .latin2 .cen
ErrorLog /var/www/mysite/mysite.error_log
CustomLog /var/www/mysite/mysite.access_log combined

HostnameLookups Off
UseCanonicalName Off

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/mysite/cgi-bin/"
<Directory "/var/www/mysite/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -Includes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/mysite/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your web server settings. Apache example:

- `DocumentRoot` should point to /var/www/mysite/web
- app.dev should be one of `DirectoryIndex` values

Comment: ty i did it, i put my sites-availble/mysite code in answer above now it is app.php and 404 error

Comment: try change "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All"